# Obfuscation or e-mail spam protection for content displayed through Views module

Tags: views, advertising

Currently, SpamSpan seems to work well for anything outside of Views. Having a hard time finding a solution for e-mails that are displayed through the Views module.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

SpamSpan can do that for views too. You need to select te SpamSpan formatter on your display settings of the field.

[image: Screenshot of e-mail formatter in views]

Comment: Ok, so I go to Structure >> Views >> "View name" >> Displays >> Fields >> E-mail field. I don't see any options for SpamSpan formatter. Am I in the wrong settings area?

Comment: I've added a screenshot. Just under 'Exclude from display' you can see 'Formatter'.

Comment: Thank you for this. I don't actually have that option available under the 'Exclude from Display'. Here is what I am seeing. http://i.imgur.com/dgGS6Ry.png

Comment: The module is enabled and appears to be working otherwise.

Comment: Are you using https://www.drupal.org/project/email for the field? Or is it plain text?

Comment: Actually I believe they are custom fields. That would likely be the issue. Is there a way to allow the field to use the formatter if it is plain text?

Comment: Ah, that's the problem. Plain text is not an option, but if you can make it filtered text, then you can use an input filter with the spamspan filter on it.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, if I was going to try to make the field text filtered vs. plain where would I go to make that change?